# Is the diagonal of a matlab griddata realted directly to the x/Y input?

Tags: matlab

i want to get the elevation for a given coordinate for thousands of downhole density readings. I filter that down to the unique coordinates for each drill hole, and then make a rectangular topography grid with griddata so I can get the elevation values for the non uniform Easting/Northing coordinates per drillhole.

```
EN = [density(:,1) density(:,2)];
[uniqEN, ia, ic] = unique(EN, 'rows');
% regrid topo to the XY midpoints of the mesh
[xg yg] = meshgrid(uniqEN(:,1), uniqEN(:,2));
elevgd = griddata(topo(:,1), topo(:,2), topo(:,3), xg, yg, 'nearest');
```

Are the diagonals of **elevgd** the elevations results of each coordinate pair I input from xg and yg?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is. It makes sense if xg and yg matrices are the coordinates.